# How do I go about building the confluent kafka hdfs connector with a newer version of Hadoop

Tags: maven, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

We are using Azure DataLake Storage 2.  The `.jar` file to enable that to work required `hadoop-common-3.1.1.3.jar` whereas the Confluent connector only comes with `2.7.6` of Hadoop (and therefore `hadoop-common-2.7.6.jar`).

How do we go about building with the newer version?

Have tried editting `pom.xml` and changed Hadoop to `3.1.1.3` but it fails to build

```
<properties>
        <confluent.maven.repo>http://packages.confluent.io/maven/</confluent.maven.repo>
        <hadoop.version>3.1.1</hadoop.version>
        <apacheds-jdbm1.version>2.0.0-M2</apacheds-jdbm1.version>
        <kafka.connect.maven.plugin.version>0.11.2</kafka.connect.maven.plugin.version>
</properties>
```

If I make that change above then the following error occurs on the mvn install

```
ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project kafka-connect-hdfs: Compilation failure
ERROR] /C:/*****/GitHub/kafka-connect-hdfs/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/hdfs/wal/WALFile.java:[327,5] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
```